# syntax highlighter doesn't work after call back

Tags: php, javascript, syntax-highlighting

So I'm new to Js & php and I'm trying to print out a piece of code from a call back function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script>
            function loadXMLDoc()
            {
                var xmlhttp;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
                  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else{
                  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }

                xmlhttp.open("GET","callback_json.php",true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        </script>

        <title>Simple Cross Domain Ajax</title>

      </head>
  <body>

      <h1>.....</h1>
      <h2>.....</h2>
      <button onclick="loadXMLDoc();">Get Data</button>
      <div id="myDiv"><h2>...</h2></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

and my php file goes like

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url='someurl';
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='syntaxhighlighter/scripts/shCore.js'></script><script type='text/javascript' src='syntaxhighlighter/scripts/shBrushJava.js'></script><link href='syntaxhighlighter/styles/shCore.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /><link href='syntaxhighlighter/styles/shThemeDefault.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />";
    echo "<pre class='brush:java;'>";
    echo $data;
    echo "</pre>";
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">SyntaxHighlighter.highlight();</script>';
 ?>
```

And it seems syntax highlighter works on my php file but not after call back...I did some research and I know I'm supposed to use SyntaxHighlighter.highlight() instead of all() in the code but I've already done that. Is there any problem with my code structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<script>` tags added by innerHTML are not executed by the browser. You need to execute them manually:

```
var scripts = document.getElementById("myDiv").getElementsByTagName("script");
if (scripts && scripts.length) {
  for (var i =0; i<scripts.length; i++) {
    eval(scripts[i].innerHTML);
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can re-append the script nodes to the page instead of evaling it:

```
// ...
for (var i =0; i<scripts.length; i++) {
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.innerHTML = eval(scripts[i].innerHTML);
  document.body.appendChild(s);
}
```

but this is exactly the same as evaling the code anyway (no really, think hard about it both methods execute the code unchecked).

A better way is to avoid script injection altogether by adding the Syntaxhighlighter files at the top of the page and calling `SyntaxHighlighter.highlight()` after you've innerHTMLed the code.

Comment: Thanks that might be the problem so I changed my code and include syntaxhighlighter file at the beginning of the html page and call highlight() after xmlhttp.send() but the problem seemed still remain... what might be the problem then?